# How to extract the values dynamically using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am testing one application using JMeter. 1st I record using blaze meter and do login and do some check box action and get my input. it for one user. for multi login, for users (user id, password) I'll use user define variable. on that I need to extract some values, for that values also have some premium data. these values and premium data are inconstant. how can I extract these values dynamically? can I able extract these values dynamically using loop controller?

Answer (score 0):

The process of extracting dynamic values is known as [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) and you can extract either whole response or its "interesting" part(s) using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)

- For HTML - [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor)
- For XHTML and XML - [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) or [XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor)
- For JSON - [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor)
- For anything else - [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) or [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Once you extract what you need the value will be stored into a JMeter Variable and you will be able to replace the recorded value with the JMeter Variable from the Post-Processor.

More information: [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)